# React: custom render method doesn't return the input-label pair

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a private render method, to render a pair of label and input.

However, it is not rendering anything. I have tried out almost everything and cannot figure out the reason.

Here is the render method:

```js
const _renderLabelInputPair = (labelValue = '', inputProps = {}) = {
  <>
    <label>{labelValue}</label>
    <input {...inputProps} />
  </>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In react functional components, React expects you to return something.

```
const _renderLabelInputPair = (labelValue = '', inputProps = {}) = {
  return <>
    <label>{labelValue}</label>
    <input {...inputProps} />
  </>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Really appreciate the effort.